# Crossing Page Boundaries in Program Memory

Tags: assembly, pic

I need help with assembly codes and page crossing on program memory locations.

```
ORG  0x500;
BCF pclath,4;
BSF pclath,3;
CALL sub1_p1;
.
.
.
ORG 0x900;
sub1 :
 :
RETURN
```

If I want to cross page boundaries in program memory. For example page 0 to page 3. What code should I write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bits 3 and 4 of PCLATH register determine the page number!

Examples:

```
BCF  PCLATH,4 ;Select page0
BCF  PCLATH,3 ;Select page0
CALL xpage0
...
BCF  PCLATH,4 ;Select page 1
BSF  PCLATH,3 ;Select page 1
CALL xpage1
...
BSF  PCLATH,4 ;Select page2
BCF  PCLATH,3 ;Select page2
CALL xpage2
...
BSF  PCLATH,4 ;Select page 3
BSF  PCLATH,3 ;Select page 3
CALL xpage3
...
```

Newer PIC16xxx MCPUs use special instruction `MOVLP`.

Example:

```
MOVLP high HiProc2
CALL  HiProc2
...
```

Comment: very nice, but i want to ask you call what does xpage0, call xpage1 mean? and also this special use of    MOVLP high hiproc2 ----- CALL hiproc2 that i dont understand + its PIC16F877 ,btw thank you for answering...

Comment: @aod: xpage0 is label off your procedure on page 0. The PIC16F87X family is earliest so it doesn't support MOVLP instruction, but the latest supports. Read also: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41375A.pdf

Comment: yes , I see but, I must working on 16F877 since our course related with that... And could you more specific and detailed about how call works on with these instructions? I am newbie on the topic...

Comment: @ago: CALL instruction use only 11 bit to address FLASH, so the instruction address space is only 2K. To jump/call more than 2K then you must first set PCLATH.3 and PCLATH.4 bits. For more read datasheet section 2.3: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/30292D.pdf

Comment: I think I got it. Let me ask you one last question that I want to check myself: As far as I see, if I want to cross page boundaries of the program memory then I must set the proper bits for the proper page. This will lead to arrange PCLATH <4:3> bits and there must be a CALL instruction to go for a subroutine that located on the page that I want to use, doesn't it?

Comment: Thank you for your attention buddy really. Have a god one :))